# Disadvantages of MPI_Bsend?

Tags: mpi

I recently encountered a deadlock that I have been able to resolve by using `MPI_Bsend` instead of `MPI_Send`. If I understand correctly MPI_Bsend is a non-blocking send and it is safe to modify the thing I send without worrying about when the send operation it complete, so

```
double x = 1;
MPI_Bsend(&x,1,MPI_DOUBLE,master,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
x = 0;
```

will always result in x being sent at 1.

When reading [the documentation on MPI send mode](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/sendmode.html)s I encountered this warning about `MPI_Bsend`

> A late add-on to the MPI specification. Should be used only when absolutely necessary.

**My questions are:**

1. Why? Is it because Bsend may not be supported by all implementations?
2. What is the oldest version of Open MPI that supports MPI_Bsend?
3. Are there other cautions I should observe about using MPI_Bsend?

Comment: Make sure you read and understand the `MPI_Bsend()` semantic https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Bsend.3.php https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node40.html

Comment: There is a high risk you end up reusing the buffer when it is not safe to do so, that is why most people recommend against using `MPI_Bsend()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet what do you mean by reusing the buffer? I don't know what that term means in this context. Do you mean that if I change x later (in my example) it will affect what is sent? Or do you mean that a later send command may replace what I sent using Bsend in the buffer?

Comment: please refer to @Zulan 's excellent answer. long story short `MPI_Bsend()` is a rope you will likely end up hanging yourself with, so you'd rather be safe **not** using it. For example, you can `malloc()` a buffer, `MPI_Isend()` it and free it after the related `MPI_Wait()` completes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why is `MPI_BSend` problematic?

Buffered operations in MPI require the **user to provide a large-enough buffer**. MPI describes an operational model how much buffer may be used for each operation - so you can theoretically compute how much buffer will be needed in total. However, in in sufficiently complex applications it is **not feasible to correctly compute the amount of buffer that is needed**. Not having enough buffer space is an **unrecoverable error**. This error may be a very nasty heisenbug randomly occurring under specific circumstances.

Note that buffered mode and non-blocking mode is different (even orthogonal) in MPI. It is easier to write a correct MPI program using non-blocking primitives, i.e. using `MPI_Isend`. This is generally recommended.

## What about `MPI_BSend` support?

The "late addition" quote is misleading. It was already in the very first MPI standard 24 years ago. I wouldn't worry about support by libraries, but rather the other issues I mentioned.

Comment: How do I provide a large enough buffer?

Comment: @taciteloquence if you must set yourself on fire... it's [`MPI_Buffer_attach`](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Buffer_attach.html)

Comment: I will take that as a warning that doing so is a nightmare?

Comment: Good answer. If OP solved a deadlock problem using `Bsend`, he probably would rather need to use `MPI_Isend` and wait until other messages are received.
I personally would never use `MPI_Bsend` because you can tune the MPI library to adjust the threshold between making `MPI_Send` buffered or blocking.
If the real problem was a deadlock, then using `MPI_Sendrecv` or `MPI_Isend` is the way to go without any doubt (much better portability across MPI implementations).

Comment: By the way, the chapter in the MPI standard document has a very good explanation on the point to point messaging modes and semantics that is really worth reading.

Comment: @JorgeBellón, How can I tune the MPI library MPI_Send to make it buffered?

Comment: @Zulan I've realized that I'm confused about the different things referred to as a buffer. The send buffer is the variable you're sending (in my example `&x`), but that's not the same as the buffer that one can attached with `MPI_Buffer_attach` right?

Comment: @taciteloquence if you are confused, read [MPI: A message passing interface standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) chapter 3.4 Communication modes.
To tune the MPI library, you have to refer to the library implementation's reference manual. You can usually do that through the standard `MPI_Tool` interface or through environment variables. See [MPI_T: Tools for MPI 3.0](https://computation.llnl.gov/projects/mpi_t).
I remember seeing that in both MPICH and Intel MPI, but it may be possible in other implementations as well.

Comment: @taciteloquence, yes those are different kinds of buffers. Never rely on tuning to make `MPI_Send` "buffered" in terms of correctness.