# Mpj Bsend ByteBuffer . No space left in buffer error

Tags: java, c, image-processing, parallel-processing, mpi

I have the following code:

```
ByteBuffer colorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 3+ MPI.SEND_OVERHEAD);
        ByteBuffer depthBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 3+ MPI.SEND_OVERHEAD);
        MPI.Buffer_attach(colorBuffer);

        gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, GL2.GL_RGB, GL2.GL_BYTE, colorBuffer);
        gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, GL2.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL2.GL_BYTE, depthBuffer);
```

And I want to send colorBuffer to other process through MPI communication
        `MPI.COMM_WORLD.Bsend(colorBuffer, 1, SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT * 3+ MPI.SEND_OVERHEAD , MPI.BYTE, 0`, 1);

The problem is that I receive the following exception

```
 Error in MPI.Bsend: No space left in buffer.
```

Comment: Long story short, don't use BSend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disadvantages of MPI\_Bsend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331150/disadvantages-of-mpi-bsend)